# Rails ActiveStorage adds Black Background color to PNG Uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

Rails 5.2.6
Ruby '2.6.6'

Model

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  ################################################################## ActiveStorage
  has_one_attached :avatar
```

When the image gets upload to Digital Ocean a Black background seems to get added.

Original Image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/28403496/138166413-bf99740d-a385-463c-9962-7a11b99bf6ee.png

Post Upload Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ihGd.jpg

Comment: this link might help https://www.gitclear.com/blog/using_imagemagic_or_ruby_vips_with_activestorage